# Rescue e-mails from dead RPi card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, boot-issues

I have a RPi B that I haven't used for a while, with a Citadel e-mail server and some of my e-mails on the SD card. The card has bad blocks now that prevent RPi from booting.

Supposing that there no part of the e-mail database in those bad sectors, how can I rescue my e-mails from that card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the card on another Linux machine and copy the files to a safe place.

Comment: Thanks, that's a first step. Do you know where Citadel keeps it's e-mail database?

Comment: No, it depends on how it was installed. But there's [documentation](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/documentation:file_layout#files.and.where.easy.install.and.lhfs.rpm.deb.installs.put.them) on the net. Google!

Comment: Thank a lot! Of course I googled, not sure why I could not find that page.

Comment: It didn't show up in the list of google hits, but I dug around on the Citadel documentation site and found it.